# Save winform controls value c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application in Winform c#. I need to save the values entered by users in form control such as text box, datetimepicker etc.

What is the best of doing it? These will be read while starting the program again. I also need to save values in one datagrid, which is likely to have just about 20 rows.

Any help / pointer will be greatly appreciation.

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to create your own "state-saving" mechanism, using ini file, xml or some file based database (like sqlite). But I find this bad unless really needed.

Other approach is to use WinForms engine to save values for controls. Every control has it's own Application Settings property. You can use that property to create new Application Settings value and assign that value to some of Control's properties. That would be quick and elegant solution and it saves settings per user.

For settings that are not assigned to control properties, you can use

```
Settings.Default.SomeYourProperty
```

to access that property and you can use

```
Settings.Default.Save()
```

to save it. This might be useful for your small datagrid (because you cannot auto-assign data grid values to Application Settings property, you would like to serialize them and then save manually). Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Properties.Setting`, it's designed for exactly your use case. A very good explanation/tutorial that covers all the usual use cases (and some more) can be found [here](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33944/1954).

The MSDN has an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) too.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create your own INI Class and save up the data for each control in a text file

[here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs_ini.aspx) a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using SQLite in my program, it's working great and I have a lot of control over the data.

A Few areas of reading on this subject on [csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) and [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Before using SQLite I used [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) which is a very useful library for saving settings, it's very easy to get started.

If you want a more integrated solution without extra libraries then you can have a look at using [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) inside your visual studio solution. I haven't looked into this method at all but it might be something that you're interested in.